# PHP: How to add database result (string) as array (using explode) to null array elements in sequence

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, null

I would like to generate a multidimensional array as follows:

```
$arrayTwo = [
[ 'This','array','needs','to','be','filled'],
['This','cat','needs','to','be','filled'],
[ 'This','cat','needs','to','get','eaten'],
[ 'This','array','needs','to','get','eaten'],
[ 'This','array','needs','to','count','sheep']
];
```

I have created code which fills in the blanks using the top result from a database search, based on length and then filtered by google-results, then bing-results, then yahoo-results. However, this means if I have an array which contains multiple instances of two consecutive NULL members, then it will fill them with the same word pair every time. This would not be an issue for the first time `$arrayOne` is entered into `$arrayTwo`, as it is a valid response, but if I create a loop then I want the next formulation of `$arrayOne` to contain the selection of word groups which has the next highest values in the google-/bing-/yahoo-results sections.

---

### **Database:**

```
|column 1   |length |google-results |bing-results   |yahoo-results  |
|array      |1      |1213253        |3456365        |253645         |
|be filled  |2      |5463656        |4255665        |424535         |
|cat        |1      |4564747        |9678744        |345636         |
|get eaten  |2      |4543636        |5356456        |424253         |
|count sheep|2      |4355665        |5645647        |476578         |
|umbrella   |1      |6973435        |5356356        |346476         |
```

---

**HTML**

```
$arrayOne = [0=> 'This',1=> ,2=> 'needs',3=> 'to',4=> ,5=> ];
$arrayTwo = [];

array_unshift($arrayOne, 'Suggestion:');

for($i=0;$i<count($arrayOne);$i++) {
    if($arrayOne[$i] == NULL) {
        if($arrayOne[$i-1] != NULL) {
            $counter = 1;
            for($x=$i+1;$x<count($arrayOne);$x++) {

                if($arrayOne[$x] == NULL && $arrayOne[$x-1] == NULL) {

                    $counter++;
                }

                elseif($arrayOne[$x] != NULL && $arrayOne[$x-1] == NULL) {

                    $queryBlank = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE length = ".$counter." ORDER BY `google-results` DESC, `bing-results` DESC, `yahoo-results` DESC";
                    $resultBlank = mysqli_query($conn,$queryBlank);
                    
                    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultBlank)) {

                        $blank = explode(' ', $row['column 1']);

                        foreach($blank as $key => $value) {

                            $arrayOne[$i+$key] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            array_push($arrayTwo, $arrayOne);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me print_r($blank) when $i = 1 and $x = 2?

Comment: Sorry I think I solved that, though now I have another problem. Will update question in a second..

Comment: Okay I'm waiting for help you xD

Comment: Why you need add text Suggestion in head of array. You can do it any where except in this array. This array using for process content

Comment: I am adding it to this array because otherwise, due to the way that my code counts the blank spaces, it will not insert database entries if array[0] is blank, because there is no array[-1] to check.

Comment: So for example, the test string I am using to search is ' classical arabic please abandon hastily this vessel'.

Because the strings 'classical arabic' and 'abandon hastily' exist in the database.

So that returns: $arrayOne = [0=> ,1=> ,2=> 'please',3=> ,4=> ,5=> 'this', 6=> 'vessel'];

And then I want to fill each group of gaps with the words matching those lengths.

So array[0] and array[1] would be filled with the first and second words of all entries in the database which contain two words, as would array[3] and array[4]

Comment: So, for the example in the question, arrayOne[1] would be filled with each string in the database which only contains one word.

Comment: And now what's your problems here
I think very hard to understand all of your mind. In the first problem when you not updated. I understand but now I can't

Comment: Ok so in my actual code, I've got a search box. I have replaced that with `$arrayOne = [0=> 'This',1=> ,2=> 'needs',3=> 'to',4=> ,5=> ];`

So, between the search and this array, this is what happens:

User searches 'This array needs to be filled' in the search box on my website.

The website then searches my database for matching strings within the user input. 'array' and 'be filled' are present in the database, so they are removed from the string. During this process, the string is converted to an array.

So then it becomes `[0=> 'This',1=> ,2=> 'needs',3=> 'to',4=> ,5=> ];`

...

Comment: Then, I need to search through the array for NULL members. So, in this example, the first NULL member is `$arrayOne[1]`. There aren't any NULL members following this member, so `$counter` will equal `1`.

Then I need to search the database for all entries where `length` equals `1`. The top result will be placed in the NULL array member.

Next, the code finds NULL at `$arrayOne[4]`. It also sees that the next member is NULL. So `$counter` equals `2`. Then the database is searched for all rows where `length` equals `2` and places the top result in the blanks.

Comment: I would then like to create an array which returns the 5 most popular suggestions, measured first by length, then by google-results, bing-results etc.

However, I'm not sure how to search the top 5 arrays multidimensionally, so that the first and second set of blanks are both considered to calculate the best 5 combinations.

Comment: I'm still try understand xD

Comment: Just updated the question. Hopefully clearer now.

Comment: Please check my answer xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know my result is exactly with your mind or not

But I tried my best xD

```
$arrayOne = [0=> 'This',1=> '',2=> 'needs',3=> 'to',4=> '',5=> ''];
$arrayTwo = [];
$arrayThree = [];

for($i=0;$i<count($arrayOne);$i++) {
    if($arrayOne[$i] == NULL) {
        if(isset($arrayOne[$i+1]) && $arrayOne[$i+1] != NULL){
            $counter = 1;
            $queryBlank = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE length = ".$counter." ORDER BY `google-results` ASC, `bing-results` ASC, `yahoo-results` ASC";
            $resultBlank = mysqli_query($conn,$queryBlank);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultBlank)) {
                // echo $row['column 1'];
                $blank = explode(' ', $row['column 1']);
                $arrayTemp = array();
                foreach($blank as $key => $value) {
                    $arrayTemp[$i+$key] = $value;
                }
                array_push($arrayTwo, $arrayTemp);
            }
        }elseif(isset($arrayOne[$i+1]) && $arrayOne[$i+1] == NULL){
            // echo $i;
            $counter = 2;
            $queryBlank = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE length = ".$counter." ORDER BY `google-results` ASC, `bing-results` ASC, `yahoo-results` ASC";
            $resultBlank = mysqli_query($conn,$queryBlank);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultBlank)) {
                // echo $row['column 1'];
                $blank = explode(' ', $row['column 1']);
                $arrayTemp = array();
                foreach($blank as $key => $value) {
                    $arrayTemp[$i+$key] = $value;
                }
                array_push($arrayThree, $arrayTemp);
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach ($arrayTwo as $key => $value) {
    $newArray = array_replace($arrayOne,$value);
    foreach ($arrayThree as $key2 => $value2) {
        print_r(array_replace($newArray,$value2));
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
```

And my result

[image]

Why `count sheep` is the best match. Please recheck your database it is `5645647` > `be filled` with `5463656`

I'm not sure but you can set `ASC` or `DESC` with your mind.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a test with this though it looks like it's still missing something.

The database entries I used are not the entries present in my actual database, I just created them for an example, so the mistake in figures is fine.

Though I need the code to be universal.. would this work if the sentence made up by `$arrayOne` contained only one series of NULL members, or more than two?

Comment: For example, if `$arrayOne = [0=>'This',1=> ,2=> 'array', 3=> , 4=> , 5=> 'has', 6=> 'lots', 7=> , 8=> , 9=> , 10=> 'of', 11=> 'gaps' ];`

So that `$arrayOne[1]` is filled with all one-word database entries, `$arrayOne[3]` and `$arrayOne[4]` are populated with all two-word database entries, `$arrayOne[7]`, `$arrayOne[8]` and `$arrayOne[9]` are populated with three-word database entries, and so on.

Comment: So the code works independently of the length of `$arrayOne` or the number of series' of null members.

Comment: If that we can add more elseif and process it? You can understand?

Comment: Yes I think I understand, but the problem is that I won't know how many series' of NULL arrays there are, or how long each series is.

The user input could simply be "What is a telegraph pole?"

'Telegraph pole' would be in my database. So, in this example, the question would be converted into `$arrayOne = [0=>"What", 1=>"is", 2=>"a", 3=> , 4=> ]"`, with all two-word database matches being placed into `$arrayOne[3]` and `$arrayOne[4]`.

But the user could also copy and paste an entire wikipedia article, or their own discourse, in which case there may be hundreds of series of NULL members

Comment: I think what you have written is pretty close. I have placed it onto my website and I'm currently debugging. I'll let you know how far I get.

Comment: Yes bro xD. Let me know if have any comment.

Comment: Ok I think a simpler way to explain this, to be best applied for my purposes, would be that I want a loop which will cycle from the first NULL member in an array until the first not-null or unset member. So, 1) cycle the entire array using `for` loop. 2) Use `if($array[$i] == NULL) { if($array[$i-1] != NULL || !isset($array[$i-1]) { ... }` to determine that index is first NULL member. 3) `while(`...$array[i++] == NULL... `) {`...run the search, fill in top 5 blanks for this series of NULL members `}`. Then reset everything before the first for loop continues cycling the array.

Comment: Basically, I need something that equates to the pseudo-while loop in step 3 of my above comment^